# Spring Boot update field value to Null?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, mapstruct

I have an object that has a field with existing value, for example:

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "classID": 2
}
```

Now I want to set the field `classID` from `2` to `NULL` through `PUT` method.

This is my service code:

```java
public void updateStudent(String studentID, StudentDTO studentDTO) {

  Student student = studentRepository.findByStudentID(studentID)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException(STUDENT_NOT_FOUND_STRING + studentDTO.studentID()));

  studentMapper.updateFromDTO(studentDTO, student);
  studentRepository.save(student);
}
```

I'm using MapStruct for DTO mapping.

I tried to set `"classID": null` or an empty string `""` but none works:

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "classID": null
}
```

I'm using MySQL

Comment: Pleae make sure that classId is set to null after dto mapping

Comment: Looking at this article: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-partial-update related to MapStruct, I would check if the NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy has been set explicitly. Maybe you'll need a different mapper/config for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks @scrhartley, I completely forgot  that when using the 4.1. Mapping Strategy there's a drawback: "The drawback of this approach is that we can’t pass null values to the database during an update." I wonder if there's a workaround for this.